# How to configure a cron job for EasyAPNS on a web server?

Tags: php, cron, apple-push-notifications, jobs

how do I have to configure a cron job for EasyAPNS on a real web server?

I have the following file (cronjob.phpx):

```
<?php
    exec("* * * * * nice /usr/bin/php -f http://mydomain.com/apns.php fetch > http://mydomain.com/apns.log 2>&1");
?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank's for any help.

Arno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

1. I created a cron job file:

cronjob.phpx

1. content of the cron job file:

   include("http://mydomain.com/apns/apns.php");
2. I created a cron job on the web server

Answer (score 0):

put the full path to nice maybe it works then (/usr/bin/nice)? Try whereis nice so you know the path.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I ended up to create a crone job on the web server.